# How to accept multiple inputs as matched with multiple variables in case statement?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Choose between 1 and 2"
read -p "Enter your input : " input
echo "Choose between a and b"
read -p "Enter your input : " input2
   
case $input+$input2 in
1|2+a|b ) 
   echo "Valid Input";;
*+a|b )
   echo "Partially invalid input";;
1|2+* )
   echo "Partially invalid input";;
*+* )
   echo "Invalid Input ";;
esac
```

Even if i enter a valid input ( 1a , 1b , 2a ,2b ) , it always says that the input is either invalid or partially invalid.
As the question title implies , do i accept multiple inputs matched with multiple variables correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` (`or`) operator in the case statement has the lowest precedence.
For example `1|2+a|b` is interpreted as: `1` or `2+a` or `b`.

Would you please try:

```
case "$input+$input2" in
[12]+[ab] )
   echo "Valid Input";;
[12]+* | *+[ab] )
   echo "Partially invalid input";;
*+* )
   echo "Invalid Input ";;
esac
```

If you want to accept longer input such as `11` or `12`, please try:

```
case "$input+$input2" in
11+[ab] | 12+[ab] )
    echo "Valid Input";;
...
```

If your bash supports `shopt` builtin, you can say:

```
shopt -s extglob
case "$input+$input2" in
@(11|12)+[ab] )
    echo "Valid Input";;
...
```

where `@(11|12)` matches a substring `11` or `12`.

Comment: Thanks that seem to work , just one question i now understood that we can enter multiple inputs in square brackets but what if the input is not necessarily 1 digit or 1 word , how would we differentiate it from the other input present inside same square bracket

Comment: @Sachin thank you for the feedback. Would you please provide some examples you want to allow as inputs?

Comment: @tshiono lets say the first choice would be choose between 11 and 12 ( not 1 and 2). Then how would we go about it , i tried putting 11 and 12 in quotes but didn't seemed to work.   Example here - https://del.dog/raw/furfohisun

Comment: @oguzismail thank you for the suggestion! I've added a brief explanation.

Comment: @Sachin I've updated my answer with a version which will meet your additional requirement. Would you please try it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity , will i have to add this shopt -s extglob line everytime i use multiple case inputs or just adding once will do for whole bash script ?

Comment: @Sachin Just once put the `shopt -s extglob` sentence at the beginning of the script and you can make use of the `@(...)` type of expression in the following lines.

Comment: Just a last question really sorry for extending it a bit, i was experimenting with extglob as learned from both answers here but it doesnt seem to work in this particular script   main.sh: line 25: shopt-s: command not found
exit status 2
main.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `('
main.sh: line 27: `  @(aarch64|arm64|x86_64)+@(1) )'           script link here https://del.dog/gresteroci.sh

Comment: @Sachin please put a whitespace between `shopt` and `-s`. `shopt` is a command and `-s` is an option switch.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe character separates entire patterns, `1|2+a|b` would match `1` (no plus sign, not possible), `2+a`, or `b` (again, not possible).

With extended globs this would be way easier, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# read input and input2 here
shopt -s extglob
case $input+$input2 in
@(1|2)+@(a|b))
  echo 'valid input' ;;
@(1|2)+*|*+@(a|b))
  echo 'partially invalid input' ;;
*)
  echo 'invalid input'
esac
# shopt -u extglob if necessary
```